# How modify a graphical interface of a main window after close a secondary window?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I need your help for the conception of my application. I work with Python 3.6 and PyQt5.

I have a main window with no widget but with a menuBar. The user need to select "file" and "Create project".
After that a secondary window open with a pushButton. When I click on this button this secondary window closes.

I want to find how I can add many widgets in the main window and have the controle again of this window after the closure of the secondary window

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication, QDialog
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.createUI()

    def createUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Application')
        menu = self.menuBar().addMenu('File')
        action = menu.addAction('Create project')
        action.triggered.connect(self.create_project_pop_up)
        self.show()
        return self

    def create_project_pop_up(self):
        self.exPopup = Ui_Dialog()
        self.exPopup.setGeometry(475, 275, 400, 300)  
        self.exPopup.show()

    class Ui_Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pop_up()

    def pop_up(self):
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "OK"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.create_project)

    def create_project(self):
        self.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thank you for all of your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can do that, the simplest way I can show you is introducing the concept of signal and slot, in the same way that you used a default signal when you wrote `self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.create_project)`

So you just now would have to create your own signal and do the same logic. Now you have something like this:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication, QDialog, \
    QVBoxLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.createUI()

    def createUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Application')
        menu = self.menuBar().addMenu('File')
        action = menu.addAction('Create project')
        action.triggered.connect(self.create_project_pop_up)
        self.show()
        return self

    def create_project_pop_up(self):
        self.exPopup = Ui_Dialog()
        self.exPopup.signal_create_project.connect(self.modify_ui)
        self.exPopup.setGeometry(475, 275, 400, 300)
        self.exPopup.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def modify_ui(self):
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.lbl_project = QLabel("Now we have a new project created;")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lbl_project)

class Ui_Dialog(QDialog):

    signal_create_project = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pop_up()

    def pop_up(self):
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "OK"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.create_project)

    def create_project(self):
        self.close()
        self.signal_create_project.emit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Note:** There are many other ways to do that, but I would say that this one is the simplest example I could give you based on what you gave me. Still using the same reasoning I used with signal you could also modify the part where I set up my new UI just when clicked in the button to already have this all set up before and then when you click to create the project you just show the things that were hidden before. It's up to you choose what you really  need, I'm just giving you some ideas. ")